# Can't understand this CSS code

Tags: html, css, transform, transition

I've bought an HTML/CSS template. As I was going through the CSS files, I saw this block of code that confused me a lot.

```
.team-member .details, .team-member .details {
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
.team-member .details {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.team-member .details {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.team-member .details {
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease;
    transition: all .35s ease;
}
```

- why is the same class used over and over ?
- does the order matter ?
- what does transform-style: preserve-3d do ?
- Why use prefix with opacity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is the same class used over and over ?

There is no practical reason to that is expressed in this code.

There might be some JavaScript that enables and disables rules in the CSS dynamically, but you haven't included it.

> does the order matter ?

Not when different properties are being set (or when rules are identical). ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order)).

When a property is set to a different rules, and given equal specificity, the last rule will apply.

> what does transform-style: preserve-3d do ?

It "[Indicates that the children of the element should be positioned in the 3D-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style)." (as opposed to being flattened onto their parent)

> Why use prefix with opacity ?

To enable transluency in browsers for which the opacity property is experimental (which is pointless in 2015).

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain why the same rule (`.team-member .details`) is repeated, but one possible reason is to do with parsing; if a browser doesn't recognize some CSS property, it may skip that property and do the next one. However, certain complex properties may cause it to skip the entire rule. It's also possible that these rules were generated from some builder program.

The order matters in the sense that the last one wins. If my browser finds `-mybrowser-prop: 3`, then `prop: 5`, and the non-prefixed "prop" is supported, it will override the first property. That may be best if the behavior of the W3C-standard property is better-defined (a browser's early implementation of a property may have had differences from the 'final' that you don't want)

Preserve-3D is a bit like the positioning difference between "`position: relative`" and "`position: absolute`" for an element's children, but for rotations/transformations. It might be best demonstrated visually, if you can find some graphics of it.

An automated CSS builder that auto-expands prefixes is the only explanation for some of those prefixes though. Too much of it clutters your code, and all browsers support the opacity property with no prefixes.